# AngularJS filter example

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-filter

I'm trying to replace a string in all urls i get from json. I thought best way would be doing this with filter, although could be done with directive. Don't know which way is more correct.

Anyway i'm stuck here writing a filter which replace http:// with https:// in scope. Here is where what i got:

```
 .filter('secure', function(){
        return function(text) {
            return text.replace(/http/g, 'https');
        };
  });

{{p.link | secure}}
```

Where i'm wrong?

Comment: What's going wrong? Do you get an error or does the filter just not do anything?

Comment: Works fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/Bj87dqQKSkENXxyOQ98K?p=preview. So what's your question?

Comment: Lol, didn't included it as dependency in RequireJS.